# JQuery pagination/loading data.

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I need to paginate some data that from a database.

The data should be in a table that contains 4 rows and 4 columns.

The rest of the data should be paginated. Also, each pagination button should load the data without having to do a page refresh (ajax).

Comment: the so is not code writing service ..see the faq

Comment: As mentioned above, Stack Overflow is not a code writing service, it is for specific problems. Please post what you have tried and read the jQuery documentation for help starting out.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6726896/how-to-make-jquery-pagination/

Answer (score 1):

You can check this [link](http://www.99points.info/2010/05/ajax-pagination-create-ajax-pagination-using-php-jquery-and-ajax/) for a simple example for AJAX pagination.
You can also refer [Pagination with AJAX and php](http://www.designaeon.com/jquery-ajax-pagination/), [dynamic drive](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex17/ajaxpaginate/index.htm) and [this](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/ajax-pagination-lsv).

These would give u hints on how to do pagination with AJAX